# WP: How to disable 404 redirect for a specific page or single page?

Tags: wordpress

I need to disable the redirect function to 404 for a specific page or single page in Wordpress. I tried some examples found on google, but they dont work?

For example:

```
function no_redirect_on_404($redirect_url)
{
if (is_404()) {
    return false;
}
return $redirect_url;
 }
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'no_redirect_on_404');
```

Any idea?

Comment: please provide some sample code that you tried.

Comment: Can you edit 404.php then redirect code add to home page

Comment: Hi,  according to your answer I have to edit the 404 page and put the code there?